# sql получить определенное количество символов в ответ

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть sql запрос

```
SELECT s.name1 value, s.text1 descr, i.name icon FROM prefix_shop s JOIN prefix_images i ON s.id = i.element_id WHERE i.module_name = 'shop' and s.trash = '0' and s.act1 = '1' and s.name1 LIKE '%{$keyword}%' GROUP BY s.name1 limit 0, 25
```

что добавить, что бы в ответ в столбце `s.text1` as `descr` прилетело максимум 50 символов?

Если нельзя через `SQL`, то хотя бы через `PHP`
допустим у меня будет это

`'descr' => $row['descr']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHP` решение

```
'descr' => mb_strimwidth($row['descr'], 0, 50, "..."),
```

Comment: но почему - то иногда прилетает `null` вместо текста, так и не смог понять почему

Answer (score 0):

Можно следующим образом:

```
select LEFT('fdsfsdfsdfs', 50) from dual
```

Выводит первые 50 символов или то что есть если меньше

Comment: 'fdsfsdfsdfs' - что значит?

Comment: Строка для примера. Просто используйте функцию LEFT у себя